# Would an underwater air pocket fill up with water if water is constantly fed into it from the top, and falls back to the ocean? (See description)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, flow

Say water is constantly being fed down a pipe which runs to an underwater air pocket. The water drops from the outlet of the pipe — through the air pocket — and into the ocean. Would the air pocket fill up with water? Would the air pocket become overly pressurized? Or would the air pocket remain intact?

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: What controls the water level before you start adding water?

Comment: The water level within the air pocket? Say the air pocket is 15' below sea level, and the concave structure is 20' high and 10' across at the top (I know that's not depicted well by the picture). A valve prevents air from escaping before water is added. Pretend opening the valve isn't an issue (automated process). @David White

Comment: If the bottom of the cave is open to the sea, the water level in the cave will remain essentially constant as water is added because that "excess" water will tend to slightly increase pressure in the air bubble, but that slight increase in pressure will be enough to cause water flow out of the cave and into the sea.

Answer (score 2):

Nature generally seeks to minimize the total energy. Here, we know the system energy would be minimized if the (heavier) water were lower and the (lighter) air higher.

So does the air simply flow upwards in exchange with the downward-flowing water? Not necessarily. Here, we need to look at another energy aspect, which is the energy penalty (related to the surface tension) of forming bubbles. Small bubbles have a larger surface area for the volume they deliver, and so a small tube may not permit bubble creation and ascent because the energy penalty doesn't outweigh the upward driving force of buoyancy. (This is why you can pinch the top of a drinking straw and transport water without it falling out.)

Another potential problem with bubble ascent is the downward flow of your pumping action; such flow will entrain the bubbles to a certain extent.

If bubbles don't flow, then you will, as noted, form a sort of underwater waterfall as water falls out of the pipe through the air pocket. (Note that this waterfall may flow down the sides of the enclosure rather than dripping straight down. This is again a surface tension problem, where we need to consider the surface energy of the enclosure material.) The air won't grow more pressurized over time because it's at equilibrium with the water pressure at that particular depth, according to your diagram of an open-bottom enclosure.

So: air bubbles will rise if they're energetically stable (I think this is very likely for a 10-foot-wide opening) and if they're not pushed down by the flow (this depends on the flow rate). As the bubbles ascend, you'll see internal downward water flow that may resemble a waterfall or faucet, and the air pocket will ultimately vanish. If the bubbles can't form or ascend, this arrangement will reach steady state and persist. Does this answer your question?

**EDIT:** It's important to distinguish this device from a perpetual motion machine. The drawing shown above shows a hydraulic head—a permanent supply of water above sea level—that provides the energy for downward flow and pressurization of the air pocket. However, the water entry location could not be brought down to the surface with the expectation that the flow would continue indefinitely. That would constitute perpetual motion.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer! You mention that 10 feet is too big of an opening because bubbles are likely to rise upwards. You also mention that if the flow rate is increased, bubbles would be pushed down more. So does that mean the opening has to be big enough such that water flow is sufficiently high, but also small enough such that bubbles cannot rise upwards through the pipe? @Chemomechanics

Comment: Yes, for pressure-driven flow. Or you could just increase the flow, if that's an adjustable parameter.

Comment: would increasing the height of the pipe increase the velocity of water falling through it?

Comment: You can investigate that as a separate question. It's been discussed here many times (e.g., [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306429/fluid-velocity-in-a-vertical-pipe), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/628550/flow-in-vertical-pipe-and-bernoullis-equation), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270882/friction-loss-in-a-vertical-pipe-flow), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250004/liquid-flow-in-a-vertical-tube), ...).

Comment: (...[5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327909/how-to-calculate-pressure-drop-in-vertical-pipe), [6](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303681/how-would-you-determine-the-average-velocity-in-a-vertical-cylindrical-pipe-that), ...)

Comment: Thank you again for your time. Much appreciated